# Select objects with relationship to objects that have a name not equal to given string

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

In core data I have Entity1 which has a to-many relationship with Entity2. I need a predicate that gets me all instances of Entity1 where none of his Entity2s have a given name.

Right now I can do the opposite with

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY entity2.name = \"SomeString\""];
```

that gets me all entity1 objects that have at least one entity2 object with the name SomeString.

I need the opposite where NONE of the entity2 objects have the name SomeString.

I tried:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NONE entity2.name = \"SomeString\""]
```

but it looks like it gets entity1 objects as long as at least of their entity2 objects don't have the name SomeString, which obviously gets me back all entity1 objects

I have tried ALL

```
NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ALL entity2.name = \"SomeString\""];
```

But it crashes the app saying

> Unsupported predicate ALL entity2.name == "SomeString"'

Answer (score 1):

```
Try:

[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT(ANY entity2.name = \"SomeString\")"];
```

Comment: Sadly it didn't work :( It still returned an array with entity1 objects with entity2 objects with the name I don't want